# llc command running forever after adding new backend

Tags: llvm, llc

I would like to know is there any pass of llc that can make it stuck in an infinite loop and not give any feedback to the user?

I am working on developing llvm backend for a new architecture. I have created some '.td' files, which were working fine, but after adding load/store instructions things started to break. The backend compiled, '.ll' file was generated from '.c' file, but while compiling '.ll' file to '.s' using llc command it is taking forever to run.
Following is the '.ll' code in llvm IR:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone
define dso_local i16 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i16, align 2
  %x = alloca i16, align 2
  store i16 0, i16* %retval, align 2
  store i16 2, i16* %x, align 2
  %0 = load i16, i16* %x, align 2
  ret i16 %0
}
```

We ran llc command with -view-sunit-dags command and following dag was generated:
[image]